# Solving $x^{3}+x^{2}+1 \equiv 0\pmod{27}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How does one solve the congruence $$x^{3}+x^{2}+1 \equiv 0\pmod{27}$$ First reducing the congurence $\pmod{3}$ i get $x=1$ as one solution. But not sure how to go from here.

Comment: That means that if you reduce the congruence to modulo $9$ instead, you only have to check $1, 4$ or $7$.

Comment: And checking mod $9$ only $4$ works, so now you only need to check $4$, $13$, and $22$ mod $27$.

Comment: @Arthur If reduce mod 9 why do i have to check only for $1,4$ and $7$??

Comment: @Arthur: Ok I get it. If $a$ is a solution mod p, then I think I have to check to $p+a$ for $\pmod{p^2}$. Something along those lines.

Comment: @Jaimini Because no other possibility is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$. Specifically, $0,3$ and $6$ are congruent to $0$ modulo $3$, and $2,5,8$ are all congruent to $2$, and you've ruled those out.

Comment: @Jaimini Exactly, except that it has nothing to do with $p$ being a prime, it is more general than that. If $a$ is the only solution modulo $m$, then $a+in$ are the only possibilities modulo $mn$. If $a$ and $b$ are the only two solutions modulo $m$, then you need to check $a+in$ and $b+jn$, and no other modulo $mn$. And so on.

Comment: @Arthur Oops. I was being dumb. Sorry. :) Yeah thanks for the help